# SQLite queries to find data according to my ER diagram

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtwFU.png)[E/R diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEDGH.png)

Hi guys, I have created this database structure for my assignment. With constraints that you can see from the pic below.

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I2lX.png)

I need to find sql queries for these two question for now. But I am new to sql and not really good on complex queries. Can anyone help me?

Questions are:

1. How many comments does a specific subreddit get per day?
2. Users that commented on a specific link has also posted to which subreddits?

Comment: You have not asked a clear question, because we can't see your data, and also it appears you have not made any effort to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: I have 3 tables as shown in E/R diagram postsTable usersTable and subs Table. I have answered other 7 questions for this and stuck on these two. So wanted to ask here.

Comment: No one here likes images of code, meta-data etc so post it as text instead. And explain why we should do  your homework without any effort on your part?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands you will be unable to use the tables as per your images as the referenced columns are not constrained to be UNIQUE, as per [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

> How many comments does a specific subreddit get per day?

You use a query that uses the **count** [aggregate function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count) on the selected ([WHERE clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#whereclause)) subreddit noting that you have no way to distinguish days (unless a subreddit itself is on a per day basis).

e.g.

```
SELECT count() FROM the_table WHERE the_column = the_value_to be_matched
```

Noting that you have to ensure that literal values (***the_value_to_be_matched***) adheres to the rules for an [expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

> Users that commented on a specific link has also posted to which
>   subreddits?

Assuming that you want multiple rows in the result set and that you want the author column from the usersTable then you need to select the rows according to your criteria (WHERE clause) using a [JOIN](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/join-clause.html) to include columns from the related table (noting that if a column name is not unique that you have to prefix the column name with the table name and a separating **.** *(period/fullstop)* to resolve the ambiguity).

e.g.

```
SELECT your_table.your_column FROM your_table JOIN the_related_table ON your_table.your_column_that_references_the_related_table = your_related_table.your_column_that_is_related_to
WHERE your_expression;
```